# Getting Request parameters from Ajax Response

Tags: java, ajax, request

I am making ajax call to a java method for every 30 seconds.
I am setting few request parameters in the java method.

How can I get them from ajax response.

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2">

var tId = window.setTimeout(function () { 
location.reload(true);
alert('<s:property value="#disableReload" />');
if('<s:property value="#disableReload" />' == "true"){
    alert("clearing");
}else{
    var url = 'moveETHAction_fetchExecutorData.action';
    var form = document.getElementById('moveForm');
    var params = Form.serialize(form) + '&ms=' +  new Date().getTime();
    form.action = "fetchExecutorData";
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {method: 'post', parameters: params, onComplete: showResponseAction} );
}
}, 30 * 1000);

function showResponseAction(originalRequest){
alert(originalRequest.responseText);
    alert('<s:property value="#request[\'DISABLE_FLOW'\]" />');
document.getElementById('actionChange').innerHTML = originalRequest.responseText;
}
</script>
```

In Java method I am setting this parameter

> request.setAttribute(GenericConstants.DISABLE_FLOW, false);

But I am not getting the updated value from the ajax

Comment: I solved this problem by adding some data to ajax result jsp and based on that I am changing the original jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any changes to the `HttpServletRequest` on the server side will not be visible on the client side. Moreover `setAttribute` method will not affect the incoming `HTTP` request string. It's additional store within `HttpServletRequest` to pass-around information on the server-side.

You need to add the information to the existing response, in a structured away (JSON is preferable for your client to convert into a javascript object right away and access the individual values within response). Hope this helps.

Comment: any work around? Please I am not aware of JSON or never used it. Example for my scenario will be much helpful

Comment: can you update your question with a sample "responseText"? That would be useful to suggest any workarounds.

Comment: <b><font color="red"><s:actionerror /></font></b>
<b><s:actionmessage /></b>

this is jsp where I am sending my dispatcher and getting this action messages dynamically.

I am trying to place some variable and data for workaround. :(

Comment: is this javascript part of a jsp and are those other <s:property ...> getting replaced with the appropriate values when they come to the client side?

Comment: this is written in another jsp. yes, values are being replaces properly by struts tags

Comment: Did you try "${DISABLE_FLOW}" where you are setting the attribute in your request as `request.setAttribute("DISABLE_FLOW", "<value>");`?

Comment: yes. None of the request parameters are getting reflected after ajax call